# Magento2 - Change "LINKS" CSS class in footer

Tags: magento2, css, footer, class

I would like to change the div class "links" to something like "footerlinks", so if I change the css only the footer links are affected and not all divs with "links" as a class.

Below you can see which div class I mean.

[image]

Info: I want to change the class so I can have the linksblock in the footer side by side. Currently it is side by side because i changed style of ".links", but all the other CSS blocks with the class "links" are screwed up now..

Answer (score 1):

Add below code to your theme `default.xml` file with change your class name:-

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="footer_links">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">footer your-class</argument>  <!-- changed links to your-class -->
        </arguments>
    </block>            
</referenceContainer>
```

- clear cache

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. The problem is, I did "<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true" />", because I created 3 custom footer link blocks, which names are "footerblock1", "footerblock2" and "footerblock3". How could I handle it then? or is there a way i can have more then 1 "linkblock" in "footer_links"?

Comment: Yes you can add and change class name in block as: 
`<block name="footerblock1" class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="your-class-namel">`

Comment: Tried it, didnt work... Look, I removed the "footer_links" and made 3 new cms blocks and added them as widget to "cms footer links". now all these 3 cms blocks/widgets are in a css class called "links". I would like to change that css class "links" to "footerlinks", so the other css classes called "links" arent getting affected by css changes I need to make in order to place the footer link blocks/widgets side by side. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same problem in magento 2.1.0,
I simply changed the css and it worked:
        .footer.content .links{display:flex;}

Also, I gave the class=footerlinks to the unordered list created in each block and added the css
                  .footer.links {display: block !important;}